Declustering impact, stationarity and discretization
I have a seasonal time series, and I am considering declustering (before any other preprocessing steps) it using runs declustering. If I observe an extremal index of 1, can I claim that my data is i.i.d. and therefore stationary? Does this allow me to avoid using a non-stationary approach beforehand? Additionally, I am curious if runs declustering a time series is similar to discretization, as I am unsure if my declustered distribution still falls into the maximum domain of attraction. Thank you.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Estimators and analysis for extreme value theory

are yoou sure you really need declustering - algorithm can see here.

Why not just use DBSCAN algorithm to find Outliers as extremes ?

pay attention to Threashold Selection in EVA, or here, or here

I think, that Maximum Entropy Discrimination as algorithm for your purpose is also applicable


To conclude about stationarity - do Dicky-Fuller test or KPSS-test.


A stationary time series is one whose properties do not depend on the
time at which the series is observed. 17. Thus, time series with
trends, or with seasonality, are not stationary — the trend and
seasonality will affect the value of the time series at different
times.

or

A stationary model is a stochastic model for describing a time series
which assumes that the underlying stochastic process remains in
equilibrium about a constant mean level.

If you analyse for Extremes N.B. here

As the unit root test shows that GDP growth is stationary then you
could say that it is stationary at level. But, GDP itself may not
stationary.

also Non-stationary Extreme Value Analysis

About Extremal Index see here - it is not about i.i.d. and not about time-dependance but rather (e.g. analysing example of the severity of cold periods):


As the limiting process of exceedance times is a compound Poisson
process, we may categorize interexceedance times into two types:
independent intercluster times (between clusters) and independent sets
of intracluster times (within clusters). As mentioned at the end of
Section 2, the extremal index is the proportion of interexceedance
times that may be regarded as intercluster times

and of course, choice of threshold for Extreme Value Analysis matters for the results and estimators for this index exist different and bootstrap of estimation is needed to judge about confidence intervals

also can use declustering (like here ) for causal problems -


applied both model-dependant and model-independent stochastic
declustering methods to reconstruct the tree of ancestry and estimate
key parameters. reconstruct the tree of ancestry and estimate key
parameters


NOT for your


Additionally, I am curious if runs declustering a time series is
similar to discretization,

to descretize TS just take e.g. first differencies of your periodical measures

what is the Purpose of your analysis ?


if my declustered distribution still falls into the maximum domain of
attraction.


perhaps you'd better look through Extreme Value Theory (fitting your distribution with parametric model, like generalized pareto (as usualy python libs rely on - for Extreme Value Analysis), or any non-parametric, if exists) - if you really would like to identify return periods:


Return period indicates duration of time (typically years) which
corresponds to a probability that a given value (e.g. wind speed)
would be exceeded at least once within a year.

P.S.

If you're looking for Autocorrelations:

use ARIMA for stationary data - for Frequency analysis of TS
or AR & GARCH - for heteroscedastic data auto-regression analysis
